# A Pigeonhole-Principle from IMO Shortlist.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

I have solved a great many pigeonhole principle problems so far.
Now I am stuck with this.The statement of the problem runs as follows-

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Consider $p-1$ positive integers $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{p-1}$, none of which is divisible by $p$. Then consider all possible sums of the form $\pm x_1 \pm x_2 \pm x_3 \pm \cdots \pm x_{p-1}$. Clearly there are $2^{p-1}$ such sums. Prove that at least one among these sums is divisible by $p$.

Comment: Can we use Euler's theorem here?

Comment: Euler's theorem seems like a strange thing to look for, since there are no exponents to speak of. I mean, it's an IMO shortlist, so it's possible that the solution in some convoluted way involves Euler's, but it wouldn't be my first choice of approach.

Comment: @Arthur Actually I thought about the congruence $2^{P-1}≡1 (mod P)$ for $P$ prime

Comment: $2^{p-1}$ is just counting the number of different sums (i.e. the _number_ of pigeons). Manipulating that with Euler's makes no sense, at least to me. It is the sums themselves (i.e. the actual pigeons) that you have to manipulate with modular arithmetic, not the _number_ of sums.

Comment: @Arthur can you make any approach?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattachrya If we partition $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{p-1}\}$ into two subsets, is there any way you can use the pigeonhole principle to say that their sum will ever be the same?

Comment: @Huffman_Coding how can this be helpful?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattachrya If two subsets give the same sum, you can reverse all of the signs in one of them to give a total sum that is divisible by $p$.

Comment: You mean equality in sum modulo p @Huffman_Coding

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattachrya Yeah, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Huffman_Coding this will not use the primality of p which is the main obstacle in this problem.

Comment: @Arthur have you given up?

Comment: Doesn't all such combinations provide different sums? because if so, there are total of $2^{p-1}$ different sums. Since $2^{p-1}$ is greater than $p$, there must be at least 1 number that p divides.

Comment: @Bibekpandey plz think well before writing.Your argument is totally wrong.Don't try to be over smart about IMO problems.

Comment: Sorry, But can you please point out where the argument is wrong?

Comment: @Bibekpandey You're misunderstanding what the pigeonhole principle is. It means that AT LEAST one sum is repeated (in mod p of course).

Comment: @Bibekpandey read some article about php with deep concentration

Comment: I want to know that, whether x1, x2... xn are all different or they can be same. Because if they are different then perhaps, my first argument proves the statement.

Comment: @Bibekpandey you are not provided with any information about these numbers.please try to convince yourself that you have not yet able to understand what php is.

Comment: Okay, thanks @ShubhrajitBhattachrya

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the problem statement correctly? As written there are $2^{p-2}$ such sums, not $2^{p-1}$.

Comment: There are either $2^{p-2}$ such sums or you forgot a $\pm$ in front of $x_1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Wow what a coincidence. 10 seconds apart.

Comment: Perhaps this is a start? By the PHP, assuming you forgot a $\pm$, for $p \geq 5$ there must be at least one remainder $r$ with $p-1$ distinct $s \subset \{1, -1\}^*$ such that

$$s_1x_1 + s_2x_2 + \dots + s_{p-1}x_{p-1} \equiv r \mod p$$

Since for $p \geq 5$ we have $\dfrac{2^{p-1}}{p-1} \geq p - 1$.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg please try this problem

Comment: @orlp 4 I really forgot to give a $±$ before $x_1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using the [Cauchy-Davenport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy.E2.80.93Davenport_theorem) theorem?

Namely, consider the sets $A_i = \{x_i, -x_i\}$. Since $p$ is odd, $|A_i|=2$ for all $i$. Now observe that 
$$ |A_1 + A_2| \geq 2 + 2 - 1 = \min\{p, 3\}$$
One can now show by induction that
$$|A_1 + \ldots + A_k| \geq \min\{p, k+1\}$$
Indeed, assuming the hypothesis, the theorem gives us
$$|A_1 + \ldots + A_k + A_{k+1}| \geq \min\{p, \min\{p, k+1\} + 2 - 1\}=\min\{p, k+2\}$$
and thus at the end
$$|A_1 + \ldots + A_{p-1}|\geq \min\{p,p\}=p$$
so in fact we proved something stronger: we can write any residue modulo $p$ as a sum of the form $\pm x_1 \pm\ldots\pm x_{p-1}$.

Comment: Upon reading the other answer, this seems pretty equivalent, except we used the special case of the theorem to blackbox the explicit inductive step argument. Still, it may help appreciate better what's going on

Comment: in your proof the use of primality of $p$ is very clear.

Comment: I just want to point out that the fact that $|A_i|=2$ does not follow from the assumption that $p$ is prime but rather that $p$ is odd.

Comment: oops, thanks! corrected.

Answer (score 11):

We will prove by induction the following

> **Claim.** Let $1\le k \le p-1$ be an integer. Suppose that $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ are integers, none of them divisible by $p$. Then the set $$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \}$$
>   has at least $k+1$ elements.

**Proof.** If $k=1$ then the thesis is true. Indeed, since $p \nmid x_1$,
$$x_1 \not\equiv -x_1 \pmod p \iff 1 \not\equiv -1 \pmod p$$ 
which is true as $p$ is odd.

Suppose now that for some $1\le k<p-1$ the set 
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \}$$
has at least $k+1$ elements. If this set has $k+2$ distinct elements then clearly the set
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k + x_{k+1} \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \}$$
has at least $k+2$ elements and therefore its superset
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k + \varepsilon_{k+1} x_{k+1} \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k,k+1 \}$$
has at least $k+2$ elements as well. Thus the thesis of the claim is true in this case.

Suppose now that the set
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \}$$
has exactly $k+1$ elements. Let $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_{k+1}$ be the elements of this set.

We claim that the sets
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k + x_{k+1} \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \} = \\ \{y_i + x_{k+1} \pmod p \ \colon \ i=1,2,\ldots,k+1 \}$$
and
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_k x_k - x_{k+1} \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,k \}= \\ \{y_i-x_{k+1} \pmod p \ \colon \ i=1,2,\ldots,k+1 \}$$
are distinct. For the sake of contradiction suppose that these sets are equal. Comparing their sum modulo $p$ leads to
$$y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_{k+1} + (k+1)x_{k+1} \equiv y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_{k+1} - (k+1)x_{k+1} \pmod p,$$
i.e.
$$(k+1)x_{k+1}=-(k+1)x_{k+1} \pmod p.$$
Since $p\nmid x_{k+1}$ and $p\nmid k+1$, we have $1\equiv -1 \pmod p$, which is a contradiction since $p$ is odd. This finishes the proof of the claim. $\square$

We now use the claim for $k=p-1$. It follows that the set 
$$\{\varepsilon_1x_1 + \varepsilon_2 x_2 \ldots +\varepsilon_{p-1} x_{p-1} \pmod{p} \ \colon \  \varepsilon_i \in \{\pm 1\} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,p-1 \}$$
has at least $p$ elements. Thus one of them is $0 \pmod p$ as there are only $p$ remainders modulo $p$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: amazing use of induction and so elegant a proof!Thank you very much